# Dispatch laravel pass variable

Tags: laravel, parameters, dispatch

I'm creating manual function inside dispatch laravel. Do anyone know how to pass variable into the dispatch function()?

```
$new_user = UserAccount::create($input);
$registered_id = $new_user->ID;
dispatch(function () {
    return $registered_id;
})->afterResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dispatch(function () use ($registered_id) {
    return $registered_id;
})->afterResponse();
```

Comment: thanks! Do you know if there is any way to define infinite timeout for it?